# Creating reusable 2sxc Dynamic Data Sources

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm building a data source for internal use at our organization, and would like to use it across multiple apps.

For other parts of our apps (razor templates, JS code, etc) we are using Git submodules to keep the code centralized. A requirement of git submodules is that the repository is copied to it's own directory. However, [according to the 2sxc docs](https://docs.2sxc.org/net-code/data-sources/custom/dynamic.html#tips--common-issues), data sources must be located directly within the `DataSources` directory, Ex: `DataSources/MyDs.cs`

Is there any way (either a C# feature, or 2sxc feature, or otherwise) that would allow us to use data sources from these sub-folders? Ex: `DataSources/MyDs/MyDs.cs`, `DataSources/TheirDs/TheirDs.cs`?

An option we've considered is using a build tool to copy them to the expected directory, but ideally we would like to use something built-in if possible.

Comment: I would be curious to see more of your code-distribution setup. Maybe join us on a community meetup to demo? the last one was https://www.meetup.com/2sxc-for-dnn-and-oqtane/events/297059301 - future ones are announced on discord/facebook.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd be able to share more nuanced details, but at a basic level we wanted to use React, which requires some work in the CSHTML template to load the correct scripts with different app views (from manifest.json, we're using Vite for building). To do this, we made something similar to the Angular demo, and made that a Git submodule that we can use in various apps to get React working quicker. At this point, we're probably going to do away with that and just make a template repo to fork from, but for the custom JSON API reader Data Source I made, I wanted to reuse it somehow.

Comment: It seems to me, the best way to make the data source usable across our apps is to build a full fledged DNN module, like shown in the older Custom Data Source tutorials.

Comment: that's certainly a viable approach. A bit more difficult, but re-distribution is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now subfolders are not supported.

The feature is still fairly new, so we plan to keep it simple till we see more real life use cases. So I believe for now you'll need to improvise.